Unable to hide a custom column in checkout page based on shipping method
I am customizing the WooCommerce checkout page fields. I want to hide a custom field called "sf_region" when the pick up shipping is selected. However, after I created the field, it cannot be hidden.
I created a custom field called  "sf_region" using the code below.
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'ecommercehints_checkout_select_field' );

function ecommercehints_checkout_select_field($checkout) {


    echo '<h3 style=" font-family: var(--theme-font-family); font-style: var(--theme-font-style, inherit);">' . esc_html__( 'New field' ) . '</h3>';
    
woocommerce_form_field(

        'sf_region',

        array(
            'type'        => 'select',
            'required'    => true, // Shows an asterisk if true (*)
            'label'        => 'sf',
            'options'    => array(
                ''            => 'choose...',
                'aaa'        => 'aaa',
                'bbb'        => 'bbb',
                'ccc'        => 'ccc',
                'ddd'    => 'ddd'

            )

        ),

        $checkout->get_value( 'sf_region' )
    );

    echo '';

}

And then I want to hide it if the shipping method "pickup" is chosen using the below code but not working.
// Hide Local Pickup shipping method
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'hide_local_pickup_method_sf' );
function hide_local_pickup_method_sf ( $fields_pickup ) {
    // change below for the method pickup
    $shipping_method_pickup1 ='local_pickup:6';
    $shipping_method_pickup2 ='local_pickup:7';
    // change below for the list of fields. Add (or delete) the field name you want (or don’t want) to use
    $hide_fields_pickup = array( 'sf_region');
 
    $chosen_methods_pickup = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping_pickup = $chosen_methods_pickup[0];
 
    foreach($hide_fields_pickup as $field_pickup ) {
        if ($chosen_shipping_pickup == $shipping_method_pickup1 || $chosen_shipping_pickup == $shipping_method_pickup2) {
            $fields_pickup['billing'][$field_pickup]['required'] = false;
            $fields_pickup['billing'][$field_pickup]['class'][] = 'hide_pickup';
        }
        $fields_pickup['billing'][$field_pickup]['class'][] = 'billing-dynamic_pickup';
    }
    return $fields_pickup;
}
// Local Pickup - hide fields
add_action( 'wp_head', 'local_pickup_fields_sf', 999 );
function local_pickup_fields_sf() {
    if (is_checkout()) :
    ?>
    <style>
        .hide_pickup {display: none!important;}
    </style>
    <script>
        jQuery( function( $ ) {
            if ( typeof woocommerce_params === 'undefined' ) {
                return false;
            }
            $(document).on( 'change', '#shipping_method input[type="radio"]', function() {
                // change local_pickup:4 accordingly
            $('.billing-dynamic_pickup').toggleClass('hide_pickup', this.value == 'local_pickup:6' || this.value == 'local_pickup:7');


            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
    

}

I wonder if the custom field is created under other group so it cannot be found? But I did not managed to assign it to another group. Did I miss something? Is it the right way?
It would be appreciated if you could help!! Thank you!

Are there any errors in the console? If you change your JS eventhandler, by adding a simple console.log("changed") before $(".billing-dynamic-pickup)..., and then choose the pickup method, is anything logged to the console?

@FiddlingAway Thanks for the help! yes, there are text logged to the console.

If you were to monitor the document inspector within your browser's DevTools, is the class hide_pickup added and removed when you alternate between pickup methods? The elem.toggleClass(classname, state) looks alright, and you mentioned that the text is logged to the console, so I'm guessing - the class is added and removed properly, it's just that the CSS rule might not be applied because something else has greater priority / specificity.
